# Solidworks - The protrusion disappears when I enter into sketch mode? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: solidworks, 3d-printing, prototyping

I am fairly new to Solidworks but know basics of it (basic only). The have made a shape (which I have 3D printed as well), but I need to change the dimension of the protrusion now. Here is the design

[image]

The problem is when I enter into sketch mode as shown in the bottom right corner above, the protrusion of which I am interested in changing the depth, completely disappears. I designed this a while ago so I am not exactly sure if I cut this part out or added this as protrusion. I want to fix it but I don't know how? I do not want to create the drawing from scratch, I just want to edit this one. Any help would be appreciated. Below is where you can see the protrosion completely disappears. Is there a way to combine them or is there any way to change the dimension of the protrusion? What have done wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the cutouts are missing too.  Make sure you're clicking on the right portion of your draw history, you could be looking at the initial shape only.

Comment: Farris is correct - the face you are clicking was created in the first feature. Try clicking the side instead of the bottom of the tab

Comment: Thanks all. I came to know you can only edit the selected feature, so if you have a design which has 3 features/protrusion, only one feature or protrusion can be edited.

Comment: Hi Hammad, that's not correct. You can edit any sketch or feature at any point. Although it is true that if you make a bunch of features based on eachother and then change an early one it might break everything.

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated your situation to show you how to resolve it:

Here is your first feature - it is a simple thin extrude
[image]

You then added the tab in a later feature
[image]

The highlighted face here was created by the very first feature
[image]

Once the tab is added, this is still seen as the same face by SOLIDWORKS, even though its boundary has changed a bit
[image]

Clicking on this side face (which was *created by* the tab sketch) and clicking edit sketch, will allow you to edit the sketch you are interested in
[image]

The easiest way to do it, however, is to find the relevant feature in the history tree, and click edit sketch over there.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. I will explore the things you have explained. I did learn, if you select the feature in the assembly section, that will allow you to edit that feature. I think solidworks does not allow to edit the whole design at once, you have to select feature and can only edit that one feature at a time.

Comment: If you want to "edit the whole design at once" then you could use the direct editing tools like adding a "move face" feature

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're accidentally editing an extrusion from earlier instead of the feature you want to edit.

Your features disappear because solidworks "rewinds time" when you edit an early sketch and shows you the model as it looked when you made the sketch.

I recommend selecting the sketch or feature you want to change from the list on the left, instead of using right click -> edit sketch like you're doing.

As your part gets more complicated 1 face does not equate to 1 sketch, so when you click a face -> edit sketch, you're basically getting a sketch selected at random.

Comment: That makes sense, I will see what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Solidworks, I was told you can only edit one feature at a time. This is what I did resolve and you can say a workaround.

1. First identify the name of the part by click on it
   [image]
2. Next select that part on the left side and the click on edit sketch on level below the extrude, should bring up the sketch plan that you want to edit.

[image]